# CSS - Button disappears when resizing window

Tags: html, css

In my project, I have a button. When I resize my browser window, the button magically dissapears, when the screen reaches a width of **1042px**. When It disappears on the screen, I check the inspect tools in my browser and the element is still in the webpage somewhere, however not visible on the screen.

**HTML:**

```
<div class ="section-1">
<button class="signupBodyBtn">Sign up free, today</button> 
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.section-1 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background: url("https://images.paras.com/testimg/10100") no-repeat center center/cover;
}


.signupBodyBtn {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 263px;
    right: 683px;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 220px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

Does anybody know how to fix the issue? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have more CSS, possibly containing a media query? Also, are you using any CSS frameworks, like Bootstrap?

Comment: yes it can  j08691

Comment: @j08691 I have solved the issue, and marked the correct answer below. And yes, I am using media queries and bootstrap as-well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button is disappearing because you've set its `position` to `relative`, then set the `right` property to greater than the width of the element, causing it to appear far to the left of its parent. Browsers will automatically clip anything that appears above or to the left of the document. Here's a visual:

[image: red rectangle shown far to the left of gray rectangle]

The red box is your button, and the gray box is the parent container.

Comment: @coryward, Ah ok. So what would you recommend doing to fix the problem?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do, so it's hard to recommend a solution for that problem. If you remove the `right` property it would fix this symptom.

Comment: @eweee - you could try using a relative unit like a percent or something, rather than a fixed unit like pixels.  Or a media query when the viewport gets small enough that this becomes an issue?

Comment: @AlexanderNied Since the button is aligned left, any value > 0 on the `right` property will cause at least part of the button to be clipped.

Comment: @coreyward -- my mistake-- I misunderstood the issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

**html**

```
<div class ="section-1">
<button class="signupBodyBtn">Sign up free, today</button> 
</div>
```

**css**

```
.section-1 {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    background:url("https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg") no-repeat center center/cover;
}


.signupBodyBtn {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-left: 600px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  background-color: transparent;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 60px;
    width: 220px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 18px;
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```